# Equivalence Relation

Tags: c++

I am stuck on what to do next... The program is suppose to check to see if entered Zero-One Matrix is an Equivalence relation (transitive, symmetric, and reflexive) or not. I am still new to C++ (started this semester). I know how to create the matrix using vector but not on how to check if it is equivalence relation or not..

I assume I need to use boolean function but I'm stuck on what I need to put in as an argument or if this is correct. My original thought was... so for symmetric it will look like (which I know this goes after #include and beofre int main(). Any help would be awesome.

```
bool isSymmetric(vector<int> &vect, int Value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Value; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Value; j++)
            if (vect[i][j] != vect[j][i])
                return false;
    return true;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > vec;
    cout << "NxN matrix N: ";
    int Value;
    cin >> Value;
    cout << Value << "x" << Value << " matrix\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < Value; i++) {
        vector<int> row;
        for (int j = 0; j < Value; j++) {
            cout << "Enter a number (0 or 1): ";
            int User_num;
            cin >> User_num;
            while (User_num != 0 && User_num != 1) {
                cout << "Invalid Entry! Enter 0 or 1!\n";
                cout << "Enter a number (0 or 1): ";
                cin >> User_num;
            }
            row.push_back(User_num);
        }
        vec.push_back(row);
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < Value; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Value; j++) {
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write down the steps you would perform to manually (by hand) to test for equivalency.  Next, convert the steps into code.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I ended up doing the coding on python.